# Error with OrientDB 2.2 TLS encrypted binary connection among cluster nodes

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, orientdb

Using:
OrientDB Community 2.2.16 GA, 
hazelcast-aws-1.1.1, 
RHEL 6.7, 
openjdk-1.7.0.121-2.6.8.1.el6_8.

I have set up an OrientDB distributed (cluster). The nodes use Hazelcast to discover each other. With unencrypted connections the nodes communicate with each other. I can make queries using both binary and RESTful HTTP. Life is good. When I encrypt the RESTful HTTP connection with TLS/SSL to make queries it works. Still good. However when I encrypt the binary connection using the same TLS/SSL I get this error:

com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.ONetworkProtocolException: Cannot read protocol version from remote server.

This happens when I start the dserver.sh command on two nodes. The Hazelcast seems to work to discover the nodes (I'm using the AWS EC2 plugin). However the error message is presented when the nodes try to communicate with each other over the binary port. At this point I am only attempting to get the nodes to communicate with each other encrypted.

To reduce this problem I used the same key store for both the configured key store and trust store. Each DB node acts like both a client and server to each other. I wanted to make this simple for troubleshooting. This also matches the documentation.

The OrientDB documentation I am following:
http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Using-SSL-with-OrientDB.html

The pertinent section from my orientdb-server-config.xml file:

```
        <socket implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerTLSSocketFactory" name="ssl">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="false" name="network.ssl.clientAuth"/>
                <parameter value="config/cert/orientdb_server_key_store.jks" name="network.ssl.keyStore"/>
                <parameter value="changeme" name="network.ssl.keyStorePassword"/>
                <parameter value="config/cert/orientdb_server_key_store.jks" name="network.ssl.trustStore"/>
                <parameter value="changeme" name="network.ssl.trustStorePassword"/>
            </parameters>
        </socket>

...

<listener protocol="binary" socket="ssl" port-range="2499" ip-address="0.0.0.0"/>
```

I have tried network.ssl.clientAuth both false and true. Same result.

To create the key store, I used the same command as the documentation, I used Keytool, to create a certificate for the server. I did this on my local computer (Mac) with java version 1.8.0_92.

```
keytool -genkey -alias server -keystore orientdb_server_key_store.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 3650
```

Oddly enough, this encrypted set up works when my OrientDB client/console/gremlin/binary makes a query against a standalone DB (running server.sh instead of dserver.sh).

Would be grateful for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Binary connection means you are using HazelcastClient connection, right ?

Please also suggest what is your network configuration for Hazelcast node and client configuration. It seems more towards the hazelcast configuration issue.

Thanks
Mukul

Comment: I don't need Hazelcast when I use a binary connection against a standalone DB (server.sh). I use binary from remote client connections and binary is used between DB nodes in a cluster. I have Hazelcast using a different port than binary, 2434 (just like it comes as default). When I change orientdb-server-config.xml between unencrypted (socket="default") and encrypted (socket="ssl"), I don't do anything to Hazelcast config.